# System environment variables ignored by Nuxt

Tags: javascript, environment-variables, nuxt.js

My Nuxt project uses system environment variables to set client ids, secrets, urls, etc...

An example is in my `nuxt.config.js` where I set several properties with the following formula:

```
{
  something: process.env.SOMETHING || 'something_for_dev'
}
```

Nuxt dev version is working fine because looks after the `process.env.SOMETHING` and correctly use `something_for_dev`.

Nuxt on staging has its own configuration on Azure and the `SOMETHING` env var is correctly set but suddenly it still continue using `something_for_dev`...

What should I do to let Nuxt use the sys env vars I set on my Server rather than the default used for dev? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Env variables are set build time, not runtime. So it will be the env variables that set during your build, which seems you do on your dev machine.

So you can either build with proper env variables or use [nuxt-env](https://github.com/samtgarson/nuxt-env) module, which allows runtime variables, but keep in mind that it wont allow webpack to optimize dead code and  environment variables used in nuxt-env are exposed client side, so if you store secrets use the secret config option

Comment: This answer is correct. Even though nuxt-env has been depreciated in flavour of Runtime Config that has been introduced in Nuxt.js.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Aldarund comment above you could build a proper env variables in nuxt by following:

Use cross-env: `npm install cross-env`

In your project add a folder named `environment`
and under the folder you could have different `environment` (e.g. development, staging, production)

[image: environment folder]

Your environment configs will have your `baseUrl` and other configs, let's say for development you could have your localhost then for the staging or production you could have your `API_URL`

`defaults.json \\development` 
[image: development config]

`defaults.prod.json \\production`
[image: production config]

In `nuxt.config.ts` build > extend configure your different environment

[image: nuxt.config.ts build extend envi]

This will replace `defaults.json` depending on which environment we will run our script in `package.json`.

In `package.json` configure your script to what environment will be run (e.g `npm run start` will use `NODE_ENV=development` which will use the `defaults.json` with `baseUrl: http://localhost:3000` and `npm run build` will use `defaults.prod.json` with `baseUrl: http://www.API_URL.com` and other configs

[image: package.json cross env config]

For more detail you could see [cross-env](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cross-env)

Comment: Wait, so then you're pulling your config from these env files and not from the system's environment variables? Coz I really need to move my config out of localhost and onto the system environment. So I just want to confirm that this won't work for me for me before moving on.